# Material derivative

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If I have a material derivative, lets say 
$$\frac{D \rho }{D t} = -c\rho$$
Is the solution in the lagrangian frame of reference
$$\rho_L = \rho_{0L} \exp{(-ct)}$$
, or I is it wrong to treat a material derivative as a standard derivative?

Thanks for your time

Comment: My understanding of $D/Dt$ is that it is the operator $$\frac{D}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \vec u \cdot \nabla,$$
where $\vec u$ is the movement of the reference frame. So unless $\vec u = 0$, I don't see how the two are equal.

Comment: The material derivative is indeed a standard derivative; it's the derivative of the composition $\rho(t, \mathbf x(t))$ where $\mathbf x'$ is the flow velocity. Therefore, if I don't miss something, I think that you are correct about the solution in the Lagrangian frame (i.e. the frame that follows with the flow).